# Looping in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get my loops from controller instead of blade, here is the problem:

If I have such code in blade **EVERYTHING WORKS FINE**

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
  @php
      $data = json_decode($order->product_name, true)
  @endphp

  @php $sum = 0 @endphp
       @foreach($data as $item)
           @php $sum += $item['quantity'] @endphp
       @endforeach
  Totlal Quantity Ordered: {{$sum}}
@endforeach
```

But when I try to bring all these `@php` `@foreach`'s into controller and only get simple `{{$sum}}` in my blade everything will be messy. and I keep getting same value for all rows.

here is my current code in controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        $allorders = Order::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        foreach($allorders as $order){
            $order;
        }

        $data = json_decode($order->product_name, true);


        $sum = 0;
        foreach($data as $item){
            $sum += $item['quantity'];
        }
        $sum;

        return view('admin.orders.index', compact('orders', 'sum'));
    }
```

> PS: My data is saved as json, each  order can be have only `1` product
>   or `n` products in it.

thanks in advance.

## update

My data in database column

```
{"37": {"id": 37, "name": "test product", "price": 456346, "quantity": 15, "attributes": [], "conditions": []}}
```

My data as array in blade after

```
@php
  $data = json_decode($order->product_name, true)
@endphp
```

by

`{{dd($data)}}`

```
array:6 [▼
  15 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 15
    "name" => "test product"
    "price" => 157952
    "quantity" => 7
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
  29 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 29
    "name" => "effewf"
    "price" => 24524
    "quantity" => 1
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
  30 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 30
    "name" => "efreFR"
    "price" => 3434
    "quantity" => 1
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
  32 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 32
    "name" => "product 18"
    "price" => 1000000
    "quantity" => 1
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
  33 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 33
    "name" => "tyq53y5"
    "price" => 4567457
    "quantity" => 2
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
  37 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 37
    "name" => "test product"
    "price" => 456346
    "quantity" => 3
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
]
```

Comment: post your refactored view code

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin   `LengthAwarePaginator {#873 ▼
  #total: 4
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#868 ▼
    #items: array:4 [▼
      0 => Order {#869 ▶}
      1 => Order {#870 ▶}
      2 => Order {#871 ▶}
      3 => Order {#872 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://xxxxxx.dev/admin/orders"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin https://ibb.co/cu39bm  |  https://ibb.co/k7eAhR

Comment: @mafortis it's not unfolded. But nevermind, use shubham715 solution.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin thanks

Comment: add sample json array

Comment: @BRjava Updated.

Comment: @BRjava well? any idea?

Comment: can you expand other elements as well? want to check quantity attribute of all elements and order id

Comment: @BRjava Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should close foreach after sum .

**Try this**

```
public function index()
{
  $orders = Order::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

  foreach ($orders as $key => $order) {
      $data = json_decode($order->product_name, true);  
      $sum = 0;
       foreach($data as $item){
        $sum += $item['quantity'];
       } 
       $orders[$key]->sum = $sum;                    

      }
      return view('admin.orders.index', compact('orders'));
    }
```

In Blade Template

```
@foreach ($orders as $key => $value) 
{{ $value['sum'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I used this code now i get `41` for all my products!

Comment: if you need product quanity for every product then you need to create an array , can you tell me your expected output then i will update my code

Comment: I expect to get sum of quantity of each order separately example i have 2 products in `order->id = 5`  one qty is 1 other one qty is 4 to I want to have `5` as my oder->id =5 quantities.

Comment: are you there? any idea?

Comment: check my updated answer and now you get sum directly in view  like $orders['sum']. and let me know if you face any error

Comment: `array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array`

Comment: `Undefined index: sum` when i use `{{$orders['sum']}}` and https://ibb.co/ms72wm when i'm not use `sum`

Comment: Second: now I have my view but nothing printed

Comment: you can see some is there in output you just need to get that or else dd($orders) in blade template and show me output so i can tell you output

Comment: `dd($orders)` will return all my orders include everything! but `dd($orders['sum'])` will return `null`

Comment: loop array and print value , check my updated answer, i have checked on my side its working

Comment: Ok it return currect values but i think is because foreach, except shows each value in each order table it shows all together  https://ibb.co/ge0ahR

Comment: first 15 is belong to this orders next numbers are for next orders